# Error in if : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create a loop for calculating some parameters, but sometimes I get some errors in my loop as follows:

> Error in if (ipars1["scale"] <= 0) ipars1["scale"] <- 1e-08 :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I want something that does not stop my code, can anyone help me out with this problem?

Here is my code:

```
library(extRemes)
N=matrix(seq(150, 500, by=5))
T=length(N)
Scale.fevd =matrix(nrow=T,ncol=1)
Shape.fevd =matrix(nrow=T,ncol=1)


for (i in 1:T)
  {
  
  Scale.fevd[i]=fevd(x,threshold = N[i,],  iter = 999,  type = "GP",method = "Lmoments")$results[1]
  
  Shape.fevd[i]=fevd(x,threshold = N[i,],  iter = 999,  type = "GP",method = "Lmoments")$results[2]
  
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `T` as a variable name. `T` is short for `TRUE`, and it will make your code look wrong to use it as an object name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not working even by changing T to k or whatever

Comment: What is `x`? Does `x` have missing values? Maybe you should get rid of missing values in `x`.